# How come JsonGeneratorDelegate in Jackson doesn't implement setPrettyPrinter()?

Tags: java, json, jackson

this is really confusing! if you use a JsonGeneratorDelegate as-is it doesn't transmit calls to setPrettyPrinter() to the delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just an oversight -- feel free to file an issue to get this corrected for future versions. Delegate is supposed to delegate all calls by default.

Comment: ok. JsonGeneratorDelegate is actually kind of dangerous in other ways too, methods like enable() return the delegate instead of the wrapper!

Comment: This would also be a bug. Which version is this with? I thought this particular issue had been fixed for 2.0 -- agreed, it should return 'this', and not value from delegated call.

Comment: Ok. It's not an ancient version, but it is not maintained any more. 1.9 may have more coverage, and it is maintained (bug fixes).

Answer (score 1):

So what is your real question? You can always define your own enhanced `JsonGeneratorDelegate`, like this:

```
public class PrettyPrintJsonGeneratorDelegate extends JsonGeneratorDelegate {
    public PrettyPrintJsonGeneratorDelegate (final JsonGenerator delegate) {
        super (delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonGenerator setPrettyPrinter(final PrettyPrinter pp) {
        delegate.setPrettyPrinter (pp);
        return this;
    }
}
```